# Connect bluetooth earbuds in Mojave failing

Tags: bluetooth, mojave

I have the following earbuds model: Panasonic Wireless Bluetooth in-Ear Headphones with Sound Mic Controller & Quick Charge Function Blue (RP-HJE120B-A)

Here's my macbook Model Identifier: MacBookPro11,4
System Version: macOS 10.14 (18A391)

I am trying to pair my earbuds following the directions in the manual, but to no avail. I've paired them with my phone, but I know that that isn't interfering (I turned bluetooth off on my phone. I also tried to delete the file at `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist` also no go. Any suggestions? Other devices like computers pop up and my UE MINI BOOM speaker is showing up in the menu (though it's already been paired).

Comment: hold Shit+Option and click on BT icon, open the Debug and do the Reset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved: I misread the [manual](https://eww.pavc.panasonic.co.jp/avcacc/hje120b/RP-HJE120B_PP_EN_TQBM0049-1.pdf), but I do feel it was misworded

Here's what the manual says:

> **Pairing   (Registration)   this   unit   with   the   Bluetooth ®**
> **device   for  connection**
>
> 1 Press   and   hold   the   power   button
> of   this   unit   until   the   LED   blinks
>
> When   pairing   a  device   for   the   first   time  :   approx.   3   seconds
>
> When  pairing   a   second   or   subsequent   devices  :   approx.   5  seconds

I thought it said when pairing for the second time, but it meant second device. So just hold down longer.

Answer (score 3):

I tried a [PRAM Reset](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) and it seemed to work for me. Other things you can try are

- Check your system log
  `tail -f /private/var/log/system.log`
  If you see something like the following in your log, then likely the PRAM reset will help

`com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.preference.sound.remoteservice[4642]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by com.apple.preference.sound.remot[4642]`

- Also try the following

  - `sudo mv /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/BluetoothAudioPlugin.driver ~/Desktop`
  - Restart
  - `sudo cp -R ~/Desktop/BluetoothAudioPlugin.driver /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/`

Answer (score 0):

I had several error logs similar to the following system Logs:

```
Dec 22 23:09:01 iMac com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.WebKit.Networking): Service exited with abnormal code: 1

Dec 22 23:23:18 iMac com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.duetknowledged[813]): Service exited with abnormal code: 78
```

I simply did the "hold Shift+Option and clicked on the BT icon", as explained previously by Buscar and I opened the Debug option in the menu. However, in my Mojave system I had to do a reset and a remove a couple of times but eventually, they all connected. It's all working well now.